# ActiveX component can't create object, When using .dll/.tlb

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, dll

> Run-time error '429'

I am looking to get a little bit of help with a problem I am seeing.
I create a vb.net Class Library that I am calling from VBA in excel.
I built the solution and created the .dll and .tlb files. I opened up excel on my computer, VBA Editor, Tools, References, Added the .tlb file, test my vba macro (calling a method in the vb.net class) and everything was working fine. Then, I tried to copy the folder with the .dll and .tlb files to another computer and am having problems. One of the issues is that when i go to add the .tlb to the excel/vba references it never shows up in the list.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you register it on the other machine? or did you think just copying the file was enough?

Comment: https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=13597

Comment: @braX I just copied the files. I’m not familiar with how to register it on the other machine. Is there a good link that explains it? Thanks.

Comment: Try the link i posted above - You might use `RegSvr32.exe` to do it - I'm not all that familiar with it myself.